# Funcion en MYSQL VARCHAR

Tags: mysql

TENGO ESTA FUNCIÓN

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION PUNTOS (X INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) READS SQL DATA DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE PUNTOS INT;
DECLARE MSJ VARCHAR(100);
IF PUNTOS<=3 THEN SET MSJ='NORMAL';
ELSEIF PUNTOS>3 AND PUNTOS<6 THEN 
    SET MSJ='ADVERTIDO';
ELSEIF PUNTOS >6 AND PUNTOS <=12 THEN 
    SET MSJ='CUIDADO';
ELSEIF PUNTOS>=12 THEN 
    SET MSJ='CANCELAR';
END IF;
RETURN MSJ;
END;
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

el problem es que cuando llamo la función

SELECT PUNTOS(3);

Registra con éxito la función, pero
no me regresa nada en la base de datos, me aparece vacío, y estoy según llamando la función, alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al capturar el valor llega con el nombre `X`, el cual nunca lo usas, y declaras uno `PUNTOS` abajo, que nada tiene que ver, te propongo borrar esa declaración y cambiar a `X` por `PUNTOS`, además no es necesario el usar el if de esa manera, puesto que evalúas 2 veces algo que se puede interpretar de la siguiente manera.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `PUNTOS`(PUNTOS INT) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE MSJ VARCHAR(100);
IF PUNTOS<=3 THEN 
    SET MSJ='NORMAL';
ELSEIF PUNTOS<6 THEN 
    SET MSJ='ADVERTIDO';
ELSEIF PUNTOS <=12 THEN 
    SET MSJ='CUIDADO';
ELSEIF PUNTOS>12 THEN 
    SET MSJ='CANCELAR';
END IF;
RETURN MSJ;
END
```